# Chain Rule and powers of a function

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

Differentiating $(2x+1)^3(1-x)^4$, this is what I came up with:

$\begin{align}=&(2x+1)^3(4)(1-x)^3(-1) + (1-x)^4(3)(2x+1)^2(2) \\
=&(2x+1)^3(-4)(1-x)^3+(1-x)^4(6)(2x+1)^2\end{align}$

However my textbook further simplifies it into this:

$2(2x+1)^2(1-x)^3(1-7x)$

Can anyone help me understand how the simplification took place? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Your answer is a sum of two terms. Each term has a factor of $(2x+1)^2$, and a factor of $(1-x)^3$. So by the distributive law....

Comment: @GerryMyerson, If you put an answer I'll mark it as the correct one, the distributive law point made it click for me.

Comment: I'm happy to be of help, but I think it would be superfluous for me to post an answer now. I encourage you to accept one of the answers that has been posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a factorization. Since $2(2x+1)^2(1-x)^3$ is a common factor of $(2x+1)^3(-4)(1-x)^3$ and $(1-x)^4(6)(2x+1)^2$,
\begin{align}
&(2x+1)^3(-4)(1-x)^3+(1-x)^4(6)(2x+1)^2\\\
&=2(2x+1)^2(1-x)^3(-2(2x+1)+3(1-x))\\\
&=2(2x+1)^2(1-x)^3(1-7x).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$(2x+1)^3(-4)(1-x)^3+(1-x)^4(6)(2x+1)^2=$$
$$=-4(2x+1)^3(1-x)^3+6(1-x)^4(2x+1)^2=$$
$$=2(2x+1)^2(1-x)^3(-2(2x+1)+3(1-x)))=$$
$$=2(2x+1)^2(1-x)^3(-4x-2+3-3x)=$$
$$=2(2x+1)^2(1-x)^3(1-7x)$$